# Python websockets: how to override sync method WebSocketCommonProtocol.connection_made() with async call?

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio

Currently `WebSocketCommonProtocol.connection_made()` is defined as a sync call. If I want override it and add some async call, it seems no way to do it.

Example: I use aioredis to talk to Redis; but I cannot use aioredis when overriding `WebSocketCommonProtocol.connection_made()`. The only workaround I can think out is using a sync library redis-py in this function, but use aioredis in other places. It works but very ugly.

`asgiref.sync.async_to_sync()` doesn't work here: I already have event loop running. This commit will prevent me from using it: https://github.com/django/asgiref/commit/9d42cb57129bd8d94a529a5c95dcf9f5d35a9beb

`WebSocketCommonProtocol.connection_made()` is inherited from `asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol.connection_made()`. So this is a generic question even for python standard library. Don't know whether anyone knows a solution already.

Please give me some suggestions to solve this issue.

Comment: To make an async call (call an async function) from a sync function running inside the event loop, such as `connection_made`, use `loop.create_task(async_function(args...))`. You won't be able to see the result because `connection_made` must return as soon as possible to allow the event loop to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Worked out one solution: https://pypi.org/project/syncasync/

It will run the async code in a new thread. So it will not have a race condition with the sync code. This approach is very slow: the main thread will wait for the sync code, and the sync code will wait for the new thread to finish.

Compared to the other solution: use both sync and async libraries in your program, this solution will allow you to only use async library.

Give it a try and let me know any bugs, or suggest a better approach.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import asyncio

from syncasync import async_to_sync


class Base:
    def method(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        self.method()


class Derived(Base):
    @async_to_sync
    async def method(self):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)


async def test():
    d = Derived()
    d.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test())
```